# NoSuchElementException scraping ESPN with RSelenium

Tags: css, r, xpath, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm using R (and RSelenium) to scrape data from ESPN. It's not the first time I use it, but in this case I'm getting an error and I can't sort this out.

Consider this page: http://en.espn.co.uk/premiership-2011-12/rugby/match/142562.html

Let's try to scrape the timeline. If I inspect the page I get the css selector

```
#liveLeft
```

As usual, I go with

```
checkForServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

matchId <- "142562"
leagueString <- "premiership"
seasonString <- "2011-12"


url <- paste0("http://en.espn.co.uk/",leagueString,"-",seasonString,"/rugby/match/",matchId,".html")

remDr$navigate(url)
```

and the page correctly loads. So far so good. Now when I try to get the nodes with

```
div<- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector','#liveLeft')
```

I get back

```
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

I'm puzzled. I tried also with Xpath and doesn't work. I also tried to get different elements of the page with no luck. The only selector that gives something back is

```
#scrumContent
```

Comment: This is what I see when I inspect the page: 
`code 
<div id="scrumContent">
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div id="liveLeft"> … </div>
     <div id="liveLeft"> … </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
`
If I hover the div "liveLeft" the table I want becomes higlighted.

Comment: Yeah I have just noticed. Interesting, if you are to load the page and in the developer console input `document.getElementById('liveLeft')` it will return `null`. However, when you then inspect the element and then re-run the `document.getElementById('liveLeft')` it will return. I'm no expert in `js` but there may be some `AJAX` going on that means the element is available in the original tree, hence why it doesnt find it until the node tree is re-evaluated.

Comment: its in an `iframe` dont load the page you are currently, you want to load the `iframe`. if you look at the source code you will see the reference `/premiership-2011-12/rugby/current/match/142562.html?view=scorecard`. If you are to load that and then look for the element it should work. I havent tested in `RSelenium` so wont put it as an answer for the time being but it works in the developer tools on chrome.

`http://en.espn.co.uk/premiership-2011-12/rugby/current/match/142562.html?view=scorecard`

Comment: This works just fine! Thanks a lot. Please add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments.

The element resides in an `iframe` and as such the element isnt available to select. This is shown when using `js` in the console in `chrome` with  `document.getElementById('liveLeft')`. When on the full page it will return `null`, i.e. element doesn't exist, even though it is clearly visible. To get around this simply load the `iframe` instead.

If you inspect the page you will see the `scr` for the `iframe` is `/premiership-2011-12/rugby/current/match/142562.html?view=scorecard`, from the example provided. Navigating to this page instead of the 'full' page will allow the element to be 'visible' and as such selectable to `RSelenium`.

```
checkForServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

matchId <- "142562"
leagueString <- "premiership"
seasonString <- "2011-12"

url <- paste0("http://en.espn.co.uk/",leagueString,"-",seasonString,"/rugby/current/match/",matchId,".html?view=scorecard")
# Amend url to return iframe

remDr$navigate(url)

div<- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector','#liveLeft')
```

### UPDATE

If it would be more applicable to load the  `iframe` contents in a variable and then traverse through that then the following example shows this.

```
document.getElementById('liveLeft') # Will return null as iframe has seperate DOM

var doc = document.getElementById('win_old').contentDocument # Loads iframe DOM elements in the variable doc
doc.getElementById('liveLeft') # Will now return the desired element.
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally with Selenium when you have a webpage with frames/iframes you need to use the `switchToFrame` method of the `remoteDriver` class:

```
library(RSelenium)
selServ <- startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
matchId <- "142562"
leagueString <- "premiership"
seasonString <- "2011-12"
url <- paste0("http://en.espn.co.uk/",leagueString,"-",seasonString,"/rugby/match/",matchId,".html")
remDr$navigate(url)
# check the iframes
iframes <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])["//iframe", fun = function(x){xmlGetAttr(x, "id")}]
# iframes[[3]] == "win_old" contains the data switch to this frame
remDr$switchToFrame(iframes[[3]])
# check you can access the element
div<- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector','#liveLeft')
div$highlightElement()
# get data
ifSource <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
out <- readHTMLTable(ifSource["//div[@id = 'liveLeft']"][[1]], header = TRUE)
```